# Async ComboBox Filtration

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I am new to asynchronous methods and struggling with such a case (I made a simple example of my problem):

Let's say I've got a ComboBox, which Items are binded with a ***BindableCollection NameList *** which items are some names.

```xml
            <ComboBox
                x:Name="SubbranchComboBox"
                Margin="20 0 0 0"
                Width="100"
                Height="20"
                IsEnabled="True"
                IsEditable="True"
                IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
                InputScope="Xml"
                ItemsSource="{Binding NameList}" KeyUp="ComboBox_KeyUp">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

The **ComboBox_KeyUp** looks like this:

```
        private void ComboBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var combobox = (ComboBox)sender;
        var ctb = combobox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", combobox) as TextBox;
        if (ctb == null) return;
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift) || Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control) || Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt))
            return;
        var caretPos = ctb.CaretIndex;
        var searchedText = combobox.Text.ToLower();
        combobox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        combobox.IsDropDownOpen = true;

        CollectionView itemsViewOriginal = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(combobox.Items);
        itemsViewOriginal.Filter = ((o) =>
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchedText))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (((string)o).ToLower().Contains(searchedText.ToLower()))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        itemsViewOriginal.Refresh();
        ctb.CaretIndex = caretPos;
    }
```

and serves as search function for a **typed phrase** in the combobox.
The Problem is, I'd like the filtration to be done asynchronously, but whenever I try to do it I get an error: **The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it**

Please give me some advice, how it should be done.
All the example code:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public BindableCollection<String> NameList { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        NameList = new BindableCollection<String>
            {
                "Tony",
                "Jerry",
                "George",
                "Harry",
                "Snape",
                "Sirius",
                "Dan",
                "Michael",
                "Mike",
                "Sebastian",
                "Simon",
                "Johny"
            };
    }

    private void ComboBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var combobox = (ComboBox)sender;
        var ctb = combobox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", combobox) as TextBox;
        if (ctb == null) return;
        if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift) || Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control) || Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt))
            return;
        var caretPos = ctb.CaretIndex;
        var searchedText = combobox.Text.ToLower();
        combobox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        combobox.IsDropDownOpen = true;

        CollectionView itemsViewOriginal = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(combobox.Items);
        itemsViewOriginal.Filter = ((o) =>
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchedText))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (((string)o).ToLower().Contains(searchedText.ToLower()))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        itemsViewOriginal.Refresh();
        ctb.CaretIndex = caretPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: `itemsViewOriginal.Refresh();` is not needed. It will only force an additional update and therefore worsen the experience/performance. The filter delegate is applied as soon you assign it to the Filter property. And since the filter expression is a simple Func delegate, it can't be executed asynchronously (by the IColectionView). What you can do is to implement the expression itself async. But this wouldn't make sense in your case as you are executing a simple string operation. It will only add expensive overhead without any benefit.

Comment: Another solution would be to implement or use simple text search to filter the items yourself. This means you would have to waive live filtering in favor of improving the overall filtering performance e.g. by executing the search/filtering on a background thread. Then update the source collection with the result.

Answer (score 0):

> The Problem is, I'd like the filtration to be done asynchronously, but whenever I try to do it I get an error: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

If you want to update the UI from a background thread, you should run the code in Application's dispatcher

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => /* modify combobox here */);
```